# Load existing SQLite database to memory

Tags: java, performance, sqlite, jdbc, in-memory-database

I have an existing database in a file. I want to load the database in memory; because I'm doing a lot queries and the database isn't very large (<50MB) to fasten those queries. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

50 MB easily fits in the OS file cache; you do not need to do anything.

If the file locking results in a noticeable overhead (which is unlikely), consider using the [exclusive locking mode](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk) and have the database use these files instead of your HDD/SSD hosted files. If you have insane performance requirements your could go for a in memory database as well.

Before you do for any in memory solutions: what is "a lot of queries" an what is the expected response time per query? Chances are that the database program isn't the performance bottleneck, but slow application code or inefficient queries / lack of indexes / ... .

I think SQLite does not support concurrent access to the database, which would waste a lot of performance. If write occur rather infrequently, you could boost your performance by keeping copies of the database and have different threads read different SQLite instances (never tried that).

Answer (score 1):

Either of the solutions suggested by CL and Ray will not perform as well as a true in-memory database due to the simple fact of the file system overhead (irrespective of whether the data is cached and/or in a RAM drive; those measure will help, but you can't beat getting the file system out of the way, entirely).

SQLite allows multiple concurrent readers, but any write transaction will block readers until it is complete.

SQLite only allows a single process to use an in-memory database, though that process can have multiple threads.

You can't load (open) a persistent SQLite database as an in-memory database (at least, the last time I looked into it).  You'll have to create a second in-memory database and read from the persistent database to load the in-memory database.  But if the database is only 50 MB, that shouldn't be an issue. There are 3rd party tools that will then let you save that in-memory SQLite database and subsequently reload it.